# How to visualize the Microsupport of a Sheaf?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, derived-categories, micro-local-analysis

I am looking through [Persistent homology and microlocal sheaf theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.00955) to learn a bit on barcodes.  They are require the notion of a microsupport of a sheaf, looks like it could be a rather concrete geometric object.  In order to study this particular notion of "barcode" they require microlocal sheaves and derived categories.

The reference book of Kashiwara-Shapira [Sheaves on Manifolds](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540518617) has a through general discussion, but now it's hard to extract only the relevant parts to this one application.    As for the barcodes paper they say

> (p. 2) The main goal of this paper is to describe constructible $\gamma$-sheaves on $\mathbb{V}$
>
> (p. 9) The aim of this paper is to describe the category $D^b_{\mathbb{R}c, \gamma^{\circ a}}(\mathbf{k}_{\mathbb{V}})$.

Before we do any of that, we try to understand the notion of *microsupport* for a sheaf.

- $F \in D^b(\mathbf{k}_M)$ write as  $\mu \text{supp}(F)$ it's microsupport, a closed conic isotropic subset of $T^*M$.
- Let $M$ be a real manifold of dimension $\text{dim} M$. Let $\text{Mod}(\mathbf{k}_M)$ be the abelian category of sheaves of $\mathbf{k}$-modules on $M$, and let $\text{D}^b(\mathbf{k}_M)$ denote it's bounded derived category.

And I think we need slightly more, the notion of a $\gamma$-sheaf:

$$ \text{D}^b_{\gamma^{\circ a}}(\mathbf{k}_{\mathbb{V}}) = \{ F \in \text{D}^b(\mathbf{k}_\mathbb{V}) ; \mu\text{supp} \subset \mathbb{V} \times \gamma^{\circ a} \} $$
Here $\mathbb{V}$ is a finite dimensional vector space (such as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$) and $\gamma^\circ$ define a certain cone in a vector bundle $\pi: E \to M$

So it seems in order to learn this particular theory of barcodes, we need to understand microlocal sheaves a bit better (and I do not).  However, there is also other points of view:

- Robert Ghrist [Barcodes: The Persistent Topology of Data](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2008-45-01/S0273-0979-07-01191-3/)
- Gunnar Carlson [Topology and Data](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-02/S0273-0979-09-01249-X/)

Answer (score 8):

I'd been hoping for months that someone would come along and answer this question: every time I encounter the definition of microsupport, my brain responds with a flash of anger followed by a protracted period of profound sadness. I hope that someone with a deeper understanding of this material will eventually descend from the heavens and show us a better way than the following.

---

Start with simplifying everything until it starts to look ridiculous. $\mathscr{F}$ is not a complex of sheaves in the derived category, but rather a single sheaf (which, if you are addicted to complexes, you can think of as being concentrated in degree zero). And rather than taking values in the category of $R$-modules for a hideous ring $R$, let's just assume we are dealing with vector spaces over a nice field ($\mathbb{Q,R,C} \ldots)$. I'll assume that you can "visualize" things like the cohomology $H^\bullet(U;\mathscr{F})$ for open sets $U \subset X$ --- this is already difficult unless you are used to thinking of sheaves in terms of their leaf spaces.

What we know for certain is that the microsupport $\text{SS}(\mathscr{F})$ lives inside the cotangent bundle $T^*X$. If you'll allow me the usual conflation of a vector space with its dual (through an inner product structure), then we can try to visualize microsupports in the tangent bundle. This contains all pairs $(x,v)$ where $x$ is a point of $X$ while $v$ lies in the tangent plane $T_xX$. If you flatten everything out by passing to a local chart around $x$, the picture is something like this:

[image]

The important point is that $v$ describes a half-space in the usual manner, consisting of all vectors in $T_xX$ whose inner product with $v$ is non-negative; and intersections of open sets $U$ around $x$ with this half-space will determine whether or not our pair $(x,v)$ lies in the microsupport $\text{SS}(\mathscr{F})$. Here is a picture:

[image]

Writing $U_v$ for the intersection of $U$ with the interior of our half-space, the cohomology group of interest is $H^\bullet_c(U_v;\mathscr{F})$, where the subscript $c$ indicates compact support. One then takes a limit over decreasing $U$. If this limiting cohomology group is zero, then the "directional derivative" of the sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ along $v$ is trivial, meaning that the sheaf propagates infinitesimally without loss of information along $v$. In this case, $(x,v)$ is not in the microsupport. But if that limiting cohomology group is not zero, then there is a phase transition in the overlaid algebraic data, in which case $(x,v)$ lies in $\text{SS}(\mathscr{F})$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am right now only working through Kashiwara-Schapira, so take this with a grain of salt, but something looks a bit off to me.  Let $H_v$ be the closed half-space corresponding to $v$ as in the answer. Then if $F$ is the constant sheaf on $H_v$, we should get only $(0,v)$ in the microsupport of $F$ at 0, and it seems we do get exactly that in this answer. However, if we look at the constant sheaf on the open half-space, we should get $(0,-v)$ in the microsupport of $F$ at 0, and this I just can not see from this picture. I think something funny happens if $F$ has non-closed support.

Answer (score 5):

This might be too late, or out-of-date for you, but I've always understood the microsupport best in terms of Morse theory (or microlocal Morse theory, or the stratified Morse theory of Goresky-MacPherson).

In classical Morse theory, if $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth proper function with no critical values in some closed interval $[a,b]$, then the sub-level sets $M_{\leq a} = f^{-1}(-\infty,a]$ and $M_{\leq b} = f^{-1}(-\infty,b]$ are diffeomorphic, with diffeomorphism given by flowing along the one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms induced by (the dual of) $df$. Homologically, this says $H^k(M_{\leq b},M_{\leq a};\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ for all $k$. Sheaf-theoretically, the derived pushforwards $R^k f_*\mathbb{Z}_M^\bullet$ are locally constant sheaves over the interval $[a,b]$.

Microlocally speaking, we'd say (in the first case, with no critical points) that $SS(Rf_*\mathbb{Z}_M^\bullet)$ is just the zero section (away from the endpoints), not saying anything there.

If $f$ has a single (non-degenerate) critical point $p$ of index $\lambda$ over the interval $(a,b)$, then $M_{\leq b}$ is obtained from $M_{\leq a}$ by smoothly attaching a $\lambda$-handle. Homologically, this says $H^{\dim M-k}(M_{\leq b},M_{\leq a};\mathbb{Z}) = 0$ except for $k = \lambda$, where it is a single copy of $\mathbb{Z}$. Sheaf theoretically, changes in the topology of sub-level sets are detected by the failure of (the cohomology sheaves of) $Rf_*\mathbb{Z}_M^\bullet$ to be locally constant over $[a,b]$.

Microlocally, we'd detect $(p,d_pf) \in SS(Rf_*\mathbb{Z}_M^\bullet)$.

It isn't really incorrect to think of the microsupport of a general complex $F^\bullet \in D^b(\mathbb{Z}_M)$ in this way, as a subset of the cotangent bundle that sees "generalized critical points of functions with coefficients in $F^\bullet$". In fact, in the complex-constructible setting, this is an equivalent way of thinking about the microsupport:

**Theorem** (somewhere near the end of section 8.6 of "Sheaves on Manifolds"):

*$(p,d_pf) \in SS(F^\bullet)$ if and only if $\phi_f F^\bullet_p \neq 0$.*

where $\phi_f$ is the vanishing cycles functor along $f$.

This is also perhaps the best way to understand Kashiwara-Schapira's "local type" construction for a complex $F^\bullet \in D_{\mathbb{C}-c}^b(\mathbb{Z}_M)$, where purity of local type is equivalent to (middle) perversity.

Comment: Kashiwara's book was really technical.

Comment: In his own words, "I didn't invent it to be easy."

Comment: In what sense are vanishing cycles "generalized critical points" in your analogy?

Comment: Via either the Morse theoretic interpretation (thm 8.6.4 of sheaves on manifolds+ Cor. 5.4.19 which is a microlocal version of the Morse theory thm I referenced above), or from singularity theory: the cohomology of the Milnor fiber of a function $f$ at a point $p$ is given by the stalk cohomology of the vanishing cycles of that function (with integral coefficients classically but you can plug arbitrary C-constructible complexes in), and the Milnor fiber having trivial cohomology is equivalent to $p$ not being a critical point of $f$ (in the case where $f$ is reduced and we're on a manifold).

Comment: Thanks! Forgot to follow this comment for notifications :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you write $(p,d_pf) \in SS(Rf_*\mathbb{Z}_M^\bullet)$? $p$ lies in $M$ right? But the right hand side is a subset of $T^*\mathbb{R}$. I think to apply the theorem you site, we should take $f=x-f(p)$, where $x$ is a coordinate on $\mathbb{R}$, and thus we find that $T_{f(p)}^*\mathbb{R}\subset SS(Rf_*\mathbb{Z}_M^\bullet)$, right?